# C# view inserted data without need any button to view

Tags: c#

I have to buttons, namely `Insert` and `View`. The Problem is that every time I press `Insert` in order to data into my database it necessarily needs to hit the button `View` in order to view the data stored on my database and display in `dataGridView`.

What I want is every time I press the `Insert` button, the user doesn't need to press `View` button. I don't know how to insert the code for `View` into the `Insert` button.

This is my codes for `Insert`:

```
{
    con.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into customerOrder values('"+txtFname.Text+"','"+txtLname.Text+"')";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    txtFname.Text = "";
    txtLname.Text = "";
    MessageBox.Show("Inserted Successfully!");

}
```

And this is the code for `View`:

```
{
    con.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from customerOrder";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    con.Close();

}
```

Comment: Add the View code to a separate method and at the end of Insert call View Method

Comment: I don't know how sir/maam.. can you pls rewrite the codes plsssss? am stock on this.. am still noob :(

Comment: Insert()  {  if (successful_insert) { View(); }  }    Please do not expect people to re-write the codes, they can only provide guidance at specific area you are getting struck.

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulate them in separate method like

```
public void InsertData()
{
    con.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into customerOrder values('"+txtFname.Text+"','"+txtLname.Text+"')";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    txtFname.Text = "";
    txtLname.Text = "";
    MessageBox.Show("Inserted Successfully!");

}

Public void ViewData()
    {
        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from customerOrder";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        con.Close();

    }
```

Now in your Insert event handler call them like

```
protected void Insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  InsertData();
  ViewData();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can if you wish you call the Procdure for the view event

```
private void cmd_Insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /**Do insert here **//
    cmd_View_Click(sender, e);
}

private void cmd_View_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /**Do View here **//
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have each code on a separate Method, like:

```
void Insert()
{
        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into customerOrder values(@Fname,@Lname)";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fname",SqlDbType.NVarchar).Value = txtFname.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Lname",SqlDbType.NVarchar).Value = txtLname.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        txtFname.Text = "";
        txtLname.Text = "";
        MessageBox.Show("Inserted Successfully!");    
 }

void View()
 {
        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from customerOrder";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        con.Close();
    }
```

And then on Insert Button Click Have:

```
private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Insert();
    View();
}
```

Also notice the use of **SQL parameters** on Insert Method. It is very important to use them instead of concatenating  string

Answer (score 0):

You just have to insert the `View`'s code to **insertButton's** code.

```
        private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into customerOrder values('" + txtFname.Text + "','" + txtLname.Text + "')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            txtFname.Text = "";
            txtLname.Text = "";
            MessageBox.Show("Inserted Successfully!");
            FillGridView();
        }

        private void FillGridView()
        {
            con.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from customerOrder";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void InsertButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into customerOrder values('"+txtFname.Text+"','"+txtLname.Text+"')";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    txtFname.Text = "";
    txtLname.Text = "";
    MessageBox.Show("Inserted Successfully!");
    ViewButton_Click(sender, e)
}

void ViewButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from customerOrder";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        con.Close();
}
```